# IOS Geofencing background alert

Tags: ios

I'm working on an app that alerts the user when he is close to some landmarks using the region monitoring. Everything works fine but when the app is in the background I don't get the alerts. When I open the app I get all the alerts popping up. What I wanted was to get them when the app is in the background. I'm wondering if it's possible or does the app needs to be running to get alerts? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
The problem seems to be that I used Alerts instead of local notifications. Here's the code I used:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Entered Region - %@", region.identifier);
    [self showRegionAlert:@"You are near: " forRegion:region.identifier];
}
```

How can I change this to local notifications?

Comment: In your `Info.plist`, did you declare `location` as your `UIBackgroundModes`?

Comment: actually i did which is why i think it can still track the location changes so that when i run the app i get all the alerts popping one after the other i just doesn't pop up when the app is running in the background

Comment: when you say you 'don't get the alerts', do you mean you are generating UIAlertViews when the landmarks are reached? this will not work because you can't display alerts when in the background. you should use UILocalNotifications if you aren't already

Comment: You are right, i was actually using UIAlertviews and it now makes perfect sense, any clue to how to switch to local notifications?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i didn't see your follow-up comment. check out the documentation for UILocalNotification -- the method you'll probably want is presentLocalNotificationNow:

Answer (score 7):

Check the "testing your apps region monitoring" section in

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

If you switch back and forth between foreground and background the threshold conditions might not be met and trigger before you bring the app to the foreground again.

Also when the backgrounded app gets a notification there is only a small window for processing the message. Trying to do network requests might time out...

Check your plist settings - declare location as UIBackgroundModes only required if you need high precision positioning. The significant location changes works even without location defined.

Check that locationManager:didUpdateLocations: and locationManager:didFailWithError: are being called and no errors are posted.

Check that you haven't set ApplicationRunsInBackground to NO in your plist.

Try implementing the AppDelegates applicationDidEnterBackground:, application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and friends to spot where in the app lifecycle you are at a given time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually i read this and here's my problem when in the background the app monitors teh regions i can even see it in the console but the problem is that i don't get any alert while the app is till in the background. when i start it i get the alerts for all the events that occured while it was in the background

Comment: Actually the problem seems to be that i used UIAlert and not the local notifications, i updated my question with the code i used, do you know how i can switch that to localnotifications instead of alerts?

Comment: I found http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/ verbose and helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Yes! Welcome to %@",region.identifier);
    UILocalNotification* notify = [UILocalNotification new];
    notify.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome to %@",region.identifier];
    notify.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    if (notify.applicationIconBadgeNumber == 0) {
        notify.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notify];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For geofencing solution, you can refer the answer given by @Niels Castle.
2. For local notification, you can refer below code:

> ```
> UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
>
> localNotification.alertBody = @"I'M IN THE REGION";
>
> localNotification.userInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"nearBy",@"type", nil];
>
> localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
>
> localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
>
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
> ```